# How to show the validation error message of a data on the screen with append?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, forms

I'm trying to sketch as in the image below the mistakes made by mis-inserting data into the form.

However, it only works when the data is entered correctly. It should show "Invalid CPF", for example.

[image]

JavaScript code:

```
$("#formCadastro").on("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var dados = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: getRoot() + 'controllers/controllerCadastro',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: dados,
        success: function (xhr) {
            $(".retornoCad").empty();
            $(".retornoCad").append("Dados inseridos com sucesso!");
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            $(".retornoCad").empty();
            getCaptcha();
            $.each(xhr.response, function(key,value){
                $(".retornoCad").append(value + '<br>');
            });
            
        }
    });
    
});
```

And the .php file for validation is:

```
    public function validateFinalCad($arrVar)
    {
        if (count($this->getErro()) > 0) {
        
            $arrResponse = [
                // print_r($this->getErro())
                "retorno" => "erro",
                "erros" => print_r($this->getErro())
            ];
        } else {
           $arrResponse = [
                // print_r($this->getErro())
                "retorno" => "success",
                "erros" => null
            ];
            /*$this->cadastro->insertCad($arrVar);*/
        }
        return json_encode($arrResponse);
    }
```

Comment: The `error` callback will only run if the entire HTTP request fails (i.e. it returns a status code which is not 200 (or related such as 201 etc)). It won't go to error just because you returned some JSON which contains messages which you consider to indicate validation errors. It's not a HTTP error. Either make the PHP return a 400 Bad Request response when there are validation errors, or write code in the "success" to check the contents of the JSON and act accordingly.

Comment: I rewrote it like this:

`success: function (xhr) {
            $(".retornoCad").empty();
            //$(".retornoCad").append("Dados inseridos com sucesso!");
            if (xhr == 'erro') {
                getCaptcha();
                $.each(xhr.erros, function (key, value) {
                    $(".retornoCad").append(value + '<br>');
                });
            } else {
                $('.retornoCad').append('Dados inseridos com sucesso!');
            }
        }`
But only 'Dados inseridos com sucesso!' (success) appear.

Comment: `if (xhr == 'erro')` will never be true because xhr is an _object_. It's not a string. Try `if (xhr.retorno == "erro")` instead, to test the specific value within the object.

Comment: P.S. Next time you have a big block of code to show us like that, please use the "edit" button under your question to place it into the main question. As you can see yourself, it's quite difficult to read it when it's unformatted within the comments. Thanks.

Comment: And `$.each(xhr.erros` isn't going to do much, because in your PHP, `erros` is either null or a string (because you used print_r, which is supposed to only be a debugging tool). `"erros" => $this->getErro()` would be better (assuming `getErro()` returns an array of strings).

Comment: Thank u very much, it worked!!

Comment: Great, I added the full answer below for you to mark as accepted. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error callback will only run if the entire HTTP request fails (i.e. it returns a status code which is not 200 (or related such as 201 etc)). It won't go to error just because you returned some JSON which contains messages which you consider to indicate validation errors. It's not a HTTP error.

Either

a) make the PHP return a 400 Bad Request response when there are validation errors, or

b) write code in the "success" to check the contents of the JSON and act accordingly.

e.g. this would do the job for option (b) :

```
success: function (xhr) {             
  $(".retornoCad").empty();             
  if (xhr.retorno == 'erro') {
    getCaptcha();

    $.each(xhr.erros, function (key, value) {                     
      $(".retornoCad").append(value + '<br>');
    });
  } else {
    $('.retornoCad').append('Dados inseridos com sucesso!');             
  }         
}
```

Also, `$.each(xhr.erros` isn't going to do much, because in your PHP, `erros` is either null or a string (because you used print_r, which is supposed to only be a debugging tool). `"erros" => $this->getErro()` would be better (assuming `getErro()` returns an array of strings).

i.e.

```
$arrResponse = [
    "retorno" => "erro",
    "erros" => $this->getErro()
];
```